# Sublime Text 2 Default File Type on new file

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

I was looking around and the questions and answers did not seem to match what I am looking for. Anytime I open a new file it defaults to a plan text file. I mostly work with HTML files so I was wondering if there is a setting that would be changed so that when I open a new file it will default to HTML? Hope this is possible.

Rob

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2, you can also double click on the lower right hand corner while in an html file and choose the "Open all with current extension as..." and set it to HTML

Comment: I rcommend you to see this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520540/sublime-text-2-default-document-type

Comment: Nile, this helped me find what I needed. Just need your answer to be one that I can accept?

Comment: You can start working on Adobe Dreamweaver. I think you are asking about the Default HTML whenever you start writing the code for new HTML file.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new plugin `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...`

Paste this in:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class EverythingIsPowerShell(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
   def on_new(self, view):
      view.set_syntax_file('Packages/PowerShell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage')
```

Save and call it `NewTabSyntax.py`. New tabs will now default to Powershell.

You can change the syntax to whatever you prefer. To find out  the "path" of a particular syntax, simply open a file of that syntax, open the console (`View > Show Console`) and type:

```
view.settings().get('syntax')
```

Comment: After this all files I open are `PowershellSyntax`. Also all files with another file extension. Before, files with a file extension opened in the "right" file syntax.

Comment: It should only affect _new_ files.

Answer (score 1):

pls install Package sublime-DefaultFileType https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType

which will automatically sets the syntax for new files.

Comment: Problem. This only works if you do Ctrl+N/Cmd+N. This package does not work if you typically create new files by double clicking in tab area.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the [ApplySyntax](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax) Plugin. Once it is installed (e.g. via [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io)), you can set the ApplySyntax User Settings like that:

```
"new_file_syntax": "HTML",
```

Now if you open a new file, your default syntax will be HTML. Of course you can set every Syntax you have installed.