# Set Default Syntax for a New Created File in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2, when I double-click on the tab bar, it will create a new file, Sublime Text 2 will give it Plain Text syntax, How to change this default Plain Text syntax to HTML syntax?

I know there is a [sublime-DefaultFileType](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType) that could set the default file type of new files which are created with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. However, how can I make it take effect when I double-click on the tab bar to create a new file?

Comment: Just save the file first with a proper extension and syntax coloring comes automatically?

Comment: Or use a shortcut: CTRL+SHIFT+P and type `HTML` and then Enter. Pretty quick.

Comment: DefaultFileType has a configuration setting called `use_current_file_syntax` which, if `true`, causes the currently-set syntax to be adopted by the new file, including if created with a double-click on the tab bar. Only caveat is that its current settings are only accessible via [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/PackageResourceViewer), or manually unzipping the sublime-package file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 Default File Type on new file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814506/sublime-text-2-default-file-type-on-new-file)

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there isn't a solution for double click.

According to the official website, [DefaultFileType](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType)

```
This only affects files which are created with the Ctrl+N shortcut (Cmd+N on OSX).
```

for installation, follow the `Installation` part.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this stack post: (On Text 3 it also works fine)

[Sublime Text 2 Default File Type on new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814506/sublime-text-2-default-file-type-on-new-file)

This py code solution support double click. DefaultFileType might be an easy option. But it didn't work in some cases, it has been 5 years old. In fact, I have to use this method for text 3 on windows.

This is the syntax for SQL :

http://rouge.jneen.net/pastes/PNq0

save it like **DefaultLanguage.py**

use the default location : **\Data\Packages\User**